# Regarding sql reporting

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

i am doing a spool of sql select output.   i have  the below sql settings

```
        SET FEEDBACK OFF
        SET HEADING OFF
        SET LINESIZE 800
        SET PAGESIZE 50000
        SET TRIMSPOOL ON
        SET TERMOUT OFF
        SET ECHO OFF
```

The problem is there is  a blank line inserted into the spool file before select statement output. Not sure what sql settings i need to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's printing a blank page heading - use:

```
SET PAGESIZE 0
```